# Try to instantiate multiple instances of the same class

Tags: python

I program an educational game where the user has to reproduce a piece of factory offered by the computer.
My problem is this :

I have a string class in which there is an attribute of class "__machines" which is a dictionary in which values ​​are classes.
When I use the setConfMachine () method, I would like to change the configuration of the machine to make either a diferent line of thickness or a different number of holes. The problem is that when I configure the machine, it also configures all the machines of the same type because I believe that the machines of the same types are the same objects.

Here you have the list of the machines objects

```
[<Machine.MTrou object at 0x101c586a0>, <Machine.MRoue object at 0x101c58710>, <Machine.MPassive object at 0x101c58630>, <Machine.MPassive object at 0x101c58630>, <Machine.MPassive object at 0x101c58630>, <Machine.MPassive object at 0x101c58630>, <Machine.MPassive object at 0x101c58630>, <Machine.MPassive object at 0x101c58630>, <Machine.MPassive object at 0x101c58630>, <Machine.MPassive object at 0x101c58630>, <Machine.MPassive object at 0x101c58630>]
```

---

```
from Machine import *
from VueMachine import *

class Chaine(list):
    __machines = {0: MPassive(), 1: MTrou(), 2: MTrait(), 3: MRoue()}

    def __init__(self,nbMachines):
        list.__init__(self)
        self.nbMachines=nbMachines
        self.chaine=[self.getMachines()[0] for i in range(self.nbMachines)]

    def getMachines(self):
        return Chaine.__machines

    def setMachine(self,i,type=0):
        print(self.chaine)
        self.chaine[i]=self.getMachines()[type]

    def setConfMachine(self,i,conf):
        self.chaine[i].setConfig(conf)
        #self.chaine[i].conf

    def usiner(self,p):
        for machine in self.chaine:
            machine.usiner(p)

    def raz(self):
        pass
```

[photo of the interface](https://gyazo.com/52c834666086709102458182031f6ffc)

Could you help me ?? :'(

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please read up on
[how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a
[**minimal**, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: should i edit my post ?

Comment: yes, please! try to make an example with the **minimal** amount of code to show what you do not understand/can not achieve.

Comment: @BorisElGareh see my answer: you could [edit] your post to keep only the first few code lines. Do you want me to edit it for you?

Comment: is it ok now? Sorry i start

Comment: much better. I fixed a small other indentation problem but all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the classical "instance copy":

__machines = {0: MPassive(), 1: MTrou(), 2: MTrait(), 3: MRoue()}

```
def __init__(self,nbMachines):
    list.__init__(self)
    self.nbMachines=nbMachines
    self.chaine=[self.getMachines()[0] for i in range(self.nbMachines)]
```

this list comp doesn't avoid the instance to be duplicated because the call returns the same reference:

```
[self.getMachines()[0] for i in range(self.nbMachines)]
```

(you thought you avoided the classical `[self.getMachines()[0]]*self.nbMachines` but the result is the same)

You want to do this:

```
# dictionary of classes, not instanciated objects (note the lack of ())
__machines = {0: MPassive, 1: MTrou, 2: MTrait, 3: MRoue}

def __init__(self,nbMachines):
    list.__init__(self)
    self.nbMachines=nbMachines
    # instantiate your objects in the list comprehension: not the extra `()`
    self.chaine=[self.getMachines()[0]() for i in range(self.nbMachines)]
```

now `__machines` is a dictionary of *classes*, and instantiation is done in the list comprehension, several times so the references are distinct, like you wanted.

Note: `setMachine` must also be adapted to instantiate the class:

```
def setMachine(self,i,type=0):
    print(self.chaine)
    self.chaine[i]=self.getMachines()[type]()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jean-François !!